# Right to left letters in cards Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game where the player draws a path between some letters to make a word. the problem there that the letters appear in the cards from left to right. is that related to `Vector3`? I can't find a solution. I put values to (-1,1,1). the letters sorted from right to left but flipped. what are your suggestions please.

You may find the concept in the image below

[image]

```
public void CreateTargetWords()
{
    // Da li da kreiramo bonus slovca
    int numberOfBonusLetters = 0;
    int bonusLettersCreated = 0;

    if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 0)
    {
        // Da vidimo koliko cemo slovca da napravimo da budu bonus
        numberOfBonusLetters = Random.Range(1, LevelsParser.selectedPack + 1);
    }

    List<GameObject> allLetters = new List<GameObject>();

    if (!isBonus)
    {
        // Ako je broj trazenih reci veci od 3 onda delimo na dva holdera u suprotnom stavljamo u jedan
        if (targetWords.Count <= 3)
        {
            // Za svaku rec iz niza targetovanih reci kreiramo po jedan wordHolder objekat
            for (int i = targetWords.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                GameObject newWord = Instantiate(wordHolder, targetWordsHolder.transform) as GameObject;
                newWord.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

                newWord.GetComponent<TargetWord>().word = targetWords[i];

                // Zatim za svako slovo iz reci kreiramo letterHolder objekat i popunjavamo ga
                char[] letters = targetWords[i].ToCharArray();

                for (int j = 0; j < letters.Length; j++)
                {
                    GameObject newLetter = Instantiate(letterHolder, newWord.transform) as GameObject;

                    newLetter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterImage").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GetLetterSprite(letters[j].ToString());

                    newLetter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterImage").GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;

                    allLetters.Add(newLetter);
                }

                newWord.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Ukljucujemo odgovarajuce holdere
            targetWordsHolder.SetActive(false);
            targetWordsHolder1.SetActive(true);
            targetWordsHolder2.SetActive(true);
            targetWordsHolder1.

            // Najmanja sirina targetovanog slova
            //          float minLetterSize = 10000; // Postavljamo na brojku koja je sigurno mnogo veca od ostalih

            // Kreiramo prvu polovinu reci
            for (int i = targetWords.Count - 1; i > targetWords.Count / 2 - 1; i--)
            {
                GameObject newWord = Instantiate(wordHolder, targetWordsHolder1.transform) as GameObject;
                newWord.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

                newWord.GetComponent<TargetWord>().word = targetWords[i];

                // Zatim za svako slovo iz reci kreiramo letterHolder objekat i popunjavamo ga
                char[] letters = targetWords[i].ToCharArray();

                for (int j = 0; j < letters.Length; j++)
                {
                    GameObject newLetter = Instantiate(letterHolder, newWord.transform) as GameObject;

                    newLetter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterImage").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GetLetterSprite(letters[j].ToString());

                    newLetter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterImage").GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;

                    allLetters.Add(newLetter);
                }

                newWord.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

                //              // Proveravamo i setujemo velicinu najmanjeg slova
                //              if (newWord.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x < minLetterSize)
                //              {
                //                  minLetterSize = newWord.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
                //              }
            }
```

Comment: Please post relevant pieces of your code and / or explain in more detail the objects you're using.

Comment: I updated the code please have a look

Comment: That is way to big to be a single function. You should refactor into smaller functions. You should never write the same code twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code, you probably want to flip your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cards.Count; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = (cards.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
```

But please share some code, so we can help.

Edit: Corrected Loop.

Comment: So, either flip the loop, or change `allLetters.Add(newLetter);` to `allLetters.Insert(0, newLetter);` - It will add in "in reverse" / at the front instead of the end of the list.

Comment: flip the loop seems that doing the trick but it removes a card from ui. changing llLetters.Add(newLetter); to allLetters.Insert(0, newLetter) not help. I appreciate your help. Any suggestions

Comment: removes a card? You probably need `i >= 0` instead of `i > 0`

Comment: Thaks very much. combining two methods you mentioned did the trick. Thanks again.