# Why Letters appear in reverse order of the path (as it should be )?

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm working with a friend in building a game where player have to draw a path between some letters to make a word. The problem is that the letter appears in reversed order of the path.
My friend posted a question here but he did not present the problem correctly

Things I tried: 
* changing for-loop to :

```
 for(int i = (offeredLetters.Count- 1); i >= 0; i--)  // Nothing change
```

* Also I tried foreach with Reverse() linq.

Here is an image which show the problem:

[image: Image of the problem]

Here is my code:

```
public void CreateOfferedLetters()
 {
     float alpha = 360f / (offeredLetters.Count + offeredBonusLetters.Count);
     float firstAngle = 0;
     Vector3 startPosition = new Vector3(0, 250f, 0);

     for (int i = 0; i < offeredLetters.Count; i++)
     {
         GameObject letter = Instantiate(offeredLetterPrefab, offeredLettersHolder.transform) as GameObject;

         letter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterHolder").GetComponent<OfferedLetter>().letter = offeredLetters[i];
         letter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterHolder/LetterImage").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GetLetterSprite(offeredLetters[i]);
         letter.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
         letter.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

         Quaternion r = letter.transform.rotation;
         r.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, firstAngle);
         letter.transform.rotation = r;

         Quaternion l = letter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterHolder").localRotation;
         l.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -firstAngle);
         letter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterHolder").localRotation = l;

         firstAngle += alpha;

         // Create a selection letter
         GameObject sl = Instantiate(selectedLetter, selectedLettersHolder.transform) as GameObject;
         sl.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GetLetterSprite(offeredLetters[i]);
         sl.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
         sl.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
         sl.name = offeredLetters[i];
         sl.SetActive(false);

     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right to left letters in cards unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588868/right-to-left-letters-in-cards-unity). Your friend asked this question (twice) already. I have yet to see a reason why the answer given on the linked duplicate is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `offeredLetters.Reverse();` instead of the loop.

Comment: I tried .Reverse but compile throw an error

An implicitly typed local variable declaration cannot be initialized with `void'

here is my code with reversing with linq

Comment: var rev = offeredLetters.Reverse ();

  foreach (string value in rev)
  {
   GameObject letter = Instantiate(offeredLetterPrefab, offeredLettersHolder.transform) as GameObject;

   letter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterHolder").GetComponent<OfferedLetter>().letter = offeredLetters[value];
   letter.transform.Find("AnimationHolder/LetterHolder/LetterImage").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = GetLetterSprite(offeredLetters[value]);

Comment: Calling method `Reverse` reverses all elements in your `List<string>` object. Don't assign it to variable. Just do `offeredLetters.Reverse(); foreach (string value in offeredLetters)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Arabic Text you are using in your game. And Unity does not fully arabic support. It will always display in reverse if you copy and paste in Unity. 
You need Arabic Support plugin for this which available for free in unity store Here is the Link [Arabic Support](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/arabic-support-for-unity-2674).